# How do you make text different classes on the same line in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I want to style different parts of text on the same line in different ways. I'd like to assign items from the values array to a different class than items from the percentages array while still drawing them on the same line, but I'm not sure how. Right now I have:

```
var labels = svg.selectAll(".labels").data(values).enter();
labels.append("text")
    .attr("class", "labels")
    .text(function (d, i) {
        var labelText = values[i] + " (" + percentages[i] + "%)";
        return labelText;
    })
    .attr("x", function (d, i) {
        return labelXLeft;
    })
    .attr("y", function (d, i) {
        return labelYBottom;
    });
```

How would I assign values[i] to the class valuesLabels and percentages[i] to the class percentageLabels while still drawing the percentage text right after the values text? I don't want to try to calculate the width of the values text because the font isn't monospace.

Comment: SVG `<text>` can contain any number of `<tspan>` elements. You can more or less think of them just like regular `<span>`s within `<div>`s. So you can use `<tspan>` to style subsets of `<text>`. [Check it out](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/tspan).